# Remove an open HTML comment with PHP

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I am printing a chat log with php. As it is a chatlog, it can have user input.

I want to prevent any `<!--`  entered by the user from commenting out the rest of my file, but for some reason, my code is not working.

If there is a `<!--` open tag in the txt file, it comments out the rest of the code.
If there is a `<!-- Text -->` in the file, that "*Text*" is not echoed.

I am at a loss, as strip-tags should fix this....

I am suspecting I have an error in my code allowing this.

```
while(!feof($lfile)) {
$line = fgetss($lfile);
$lineclean = strip_tags($line);
  echo $lineclean . "<br>";
}
```

I apologize for the dirty looking code, I expanded it for troubleshooting.

Comment: Strip_tags works for me. `this is text <br>` from `$lineclean = strip_tags('this is text <!--comment-->');` Can you post a sample on input?

Comment: I am thinking the problem is where the input is coming from, but i am not sure. 

If you notice, the strip function is using the direct input from fgetss.  I changed fgetss to fget and it no longer can comment out the entire file with an open html comment tag, but it still comments the rest of the line.

Comment: If you want the contents of the comment without the comment tags themselves, I don't think strip_tags is going to work for you - "*Note:
HTML comments and PHP tags are also stripped. This is hardcoded and can not be changed with allowable_tags.*" - [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: You shouldn't strip things from your users' input. Instead you should properly escape when outputting. For instance replace `<` with `&lt;` when outputting a string of HTML. Look for a PHP function called htmlentities or something along those lines.

Comment: @Paulpro is right, although I might suggest [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) (see the [sanitize filters here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)).

Comment: Trying using `htmlentities()`

Comment: I would love to mark PaulPros answer as the answer ( Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! ) , but it is a comment.

Comment: @Ignition I was on mobile earlier and didn't want to expand on the answer or verify that `htmlentities` was the correct name of the function. Drew summed it up in an answer, so you can just accept his. Btw, when you get a chance look into using a templating language like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Twig gives you [template inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html), and by default automatically escapes all your output. It will save you a lot of time and prevent a lot of potential errors.

Comment: It helps you be more organized too, making it clear which files are templates, made for outputting HTML, (the ones that are .html.twig), and which files are logic (the .php files, which shouldn't contain any HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass everything through [`htmlentities($line, ENT_QUOTES)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and everything will be rendered exactly as it is read. This will also prevent XSS attacks and other strings with malicious intent.